# <Link> is not sending to the proper page with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to build my first website with react, and I've had a lot of trouble with navigation. I'm using react-router and for some reason my  tag is changing the url at the top of the page, but not rendering the proper component.

Here is my navbar.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class Navbar extends Component {

 render() {
        return (
          <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to={"/test"}>Test</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
          </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}

export default Navbar;
```

Here is test.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Test extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Test</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

Does anyone know why this is changing the url(as expected), but not rendering test.jsx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Route to render component for different routes.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Test from './import-path-of-test-component';

class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to={'/test'}>Test</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/test" component={Test} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: The route automatically renders the component, but I want it to be rendered on the click of the link

Comment: The Route will not automatically render it instead it will set route so that when you hit /test in the browser, it will render Test component. Usually, we provide routes in App.js as it is the component first rendered in React Project.

Comment: Ok it's working now, thanks, but it still displays the <Link> from the Navbar component, is there a way to stop this?

Comment: @IbrahimFadel it is because `Route` is in Navbar. You need to restructure the code to get it working as you want. consider this example:https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start/example-nested-routing

Comment: Thanks for the link it looks useful

Comment: Simplest solution of it is that use <a> tag instead of using <Link> as Link will cause only change in that part of DOM i.e required to be changed not whole page. But that is not good practice. As such you can define route to Navbar and Test component in App component in same way as Murli has done and then hit /navbar and click /test. You should not see <Link> then.